# Returning non-printable sybol (enter) to SQL Server from C# via CLR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, clr

I have the following CLR function:

```
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString PrintText(SqlString text)
    {
        // Put your code here
        return new SqlString(text.Value);
    }
```

And I want to get an enter symbol when passing

```
'\r\n'
```

to it. But insteat I get

```
'\r\n'
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong with this code.

Thank you.

Comment: Is what you have supplied the actual code in your function? If so, all it does is output the value which has been input.

Comment: it is. But inputting \r\n I expect it to be an enter-symbol, but it is not. Even if I pass '1' + char(13) + char(10) + '2' to it I don't get what I want. And I wonder how to achive the aim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In T-SQL you don't write a line break as `\r\n`. Instead you just use a line break:

```
'this
is a
string
in SQL
with
line breaks'
```

If you pass a string with `\r\n` to the C# code, nothing magical happens, it doesn't automatically get converted. The backslash character is just a character like any other. It's when you use the backslash in a literal string in the code that the compiler uses it as an escape code, and puts the control characters in the actual string.

Answer (score 0):

You could always:

```
return new SqlString(text.Value.Replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the SQL side, you could insert `char(13) + char(10)` into your T-SQL literals like so:

```sql
DECLARE @text varchar(100)

SET @test = 'this' + char(13) + char(10)
    + 'is a' + char(13) + char(10)
    + 'string' + char(13) + char(10)
    + 'in SQL' + char(13) + char(10)
    + 'with' + char(13) + char(10)
    + 'line breaks'
```

Though this works, it is much more verbose than Guffa's answer.

However, this technique can also be used to insert *any* character of the default code page into a string.  The Function `CHAR(int)` accepts any integer between 0 and 255.  Values outside that range cause it to return null.  The function `NCHAR(int)` accepts values up to 65535 and inserts the corresponding *unicode* characters into a unicode string.  Functions `ASCII(char)` and `UNICODE(nchar)` perform the inverse operations.